# Question about ListView binding with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm working on an app that has a ListView requiring a column with a checkbox. Below is an example of the XAML. IsSelected is part of the Items class, but I'm receiving the error "Cannot resolve property 'IsSelected' in data context of type 'App.ViewModel.ItemViewModel'". I do not receive any errors at runtime, but the XAML shows an error because it is looking for an IsSelected property in the ItemViewModel. If I add DataContext="{Binding Items}" I am no longer able to bind SelectedValue to SelectedItem.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong or how I can restructure this in order to get it working?

```
<Window x:Class="App.View.AppWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App.View"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App.ViewModel"
        xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        xmlns:ui="http://schemas.modernwpf.com/2019"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="AppWindow" Height="800" Width="1100"
        ResizeMode="CanMinimize>
    
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ItemViewModel}">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Selected" Width="100">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ItemNumber}" 
                                    Header="Item #" 
                                    Width="80"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TransactionCode}" 
                                    Header="Detail" 
                                    Width="200"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the declaration of Items in the **ItemViewModel**:

```
using App.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace App.ViewModel;

public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Property for items
    private ObservableCollection<Item>? _items;

    public ObservableCollection<Item>? Items
    {
        get => _items;
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
        }
    }

    // Property for selected item
    private Item? _selectedItem;

    public Item? SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
        }
    }
    
    // Constructor Item ViewModel
    public ItemViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Here is the model for Item in the **Model**:

```
namespace App.Models;

public class Item
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string? ItemNumber { get; set; }
    public string? Detail { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: IsSelected is supposed to be a property of the item class, i.e. the element type of the Items collection. How does its declaration look like?

Comment: @Clemens I've edited the post to include the ViewModel and Model.

Comment: Are you asking about a data binding error message that you observe at runtime, i.e. in the Output Window in Visual Studio, or just about the XAML designer.

Comment: @Clemens, I don't receive any errors at runtime. The XAML shows the error and is looking for an IsSelected property in the ItemViewModel.

Comment: So you mean the designer. Just ignore it, it is all but perfect.

Comment: Thanks, @Clemens. I twitch when I see squiggly lines, but I'll ignore it. Thanks again!